# The value of localStorage is inconsistent across tabs on one computer?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

And only on that computer, on all browsers there. Other computers are fine, with the same browser and version. Couldn't find the cause googling. Have you ever run into the same problem? What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, on that computer the address was with the `www` prefix, however `localStorage` is not shared between subdomains.